# Is there a way to put all the values of a HashMap in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashmap, iterator

I have a HashMap, let's say, with entries `{1=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=1, 6=1}` . I'd like to be able to create an array just containing `[1,2,1,1,1]`. Is that possible?

To give some context, I'm trying to get something I can iterate over using an index, and anything like an array or ArrayList would work (the order of the items does matter).

I tried assigning the values to an array using

```
for (int j=0; j< frequencies.size(); j++){
    for (int i : frequencies.values()) {
        arr[j] = i;
    }
}
```

`frequencies.values()` (frequencies is the name of my HashMap) wasn't of particular use, and I tried both iterating over that (didn't work) and assigning it to `Collections` wasn't useful. I tried assigning  `myHashMap.values()` to an ArrayList as well, which obviously didn't work.

What would you recommend?

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(frequencies.values())` didn't work?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh my goodness this worked. I had tried `ArrayList<Integer> = frequencies.values()` (replacing ArrayList with Collections worked), so I didn't think to try this. Would you be able to explain why using the new keyword worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `frequencies.values()` is a generic `Collection`, not necessarily an `ArrayList`.  As a result, to convert it to an `ArrayList`, you must *copy it* -- fortunately, `ArrayList` has a constructor that accepts a generic `Collection` and copies it.  As a result, all you have to do is write `new ArrayList<>(frequencies.values())`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kinda hacky way but it works well for me.... it assumes the values of the numbers from your hashmap are Longs.

```
Collect the values from your "frequencies" hashmap: 
1. Collection<Long> values_from_hashmap = frequencies.values(); 
        
Create an array list from the collection of values:

2. ArrayList<Long> listOfValues = new ArrayList<Long>(values_from_hashmap);
```

Boom your listOfValues array list will contain the values from the orig hashmap

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to put all the values of a HashMap in an array?

Since you did specify an array as the target you can do it like this.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1,1,3,2,4,1,5,1,6,1));
int[] vals = map.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```